# How to convert dynamic URL to statics link

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

How do I convert

example.com/company?name=famoustech to static link example.com/company/famoustech
from HTML tag

Example
`<a href="example.com/company?name=Famoustech">Famoustech</a>`

Once user click the link how to convert it to

example.com/company/famoustech

Using .htaccess also to fetch the value from database in
example.com/company page

How can I achieved this in PHP and MYSQLI
This is what I have done so far
On Index
`<a href="/company/<?= $row['company']?>"><?= $row['company']?></a>`
which look example.com/company/famoustech

On Company page
`$company_name = $_GET['company'];`
but is 500 internal server error

Comment: May I assume from the `.htaccess` tag that you are running Apache for your web server?

Comment: Yes is .htaccess in Apache

Answer (score 0):

I'm having to guess at your configuration a bit, but this probably isn't something you are going to do in PHP (unless you are already using a routing script, but I would guess you are not).

You are probably looking for [mod_rewrite](https://www.elated.com/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/) (see example 2), which is usually configured in an `.htaccess` file.

Here is an example .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ ./company/index.php?name=$1
```

mod_rewrite uses regular expressions. This file says, when you get a request that matches the regular expression `^company/(.*)$`, route the request to `./company/index.php?name=$1` (note: `$1` will be replaced with the first capture group from the regular expression, `$2` will be replaced with the second, etc).

Comment: Ok but how will I get the value back in page using GET method

Comment: After seeing the edits to the question I think I might have misunderstood you. Is your problem that you have links like `example.com/company?name=Famoustech` that you want to look like `example.com/company/famoustech`? I don't understand how the database is related.

Comment: Yes and I want to use GET method to fetch it in company page in database

Comment: Just change it to `RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ ./company/index.php?name=$1`. This should rewrite a request like `/company/foobar` internally as `/company/index.php?name=foobar`, making `$_GET['name']` accessible.

Comment: _Side note:_ Just make sure you handle a state when it's not set though, unless you have another rewrite for `/company`. If not, that path will also go to `/company/index.php`, but without any query parameter set.

Comment: M.Eriksson this my structure
project
```-index```
```-company```
```-solution```